# mysql join with a indicating column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written the following mysql query

```
select g.*, (case when count(sg.seriesid) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as checked
from genre g
join seriesgenre sg on sg.genreid = g.id and sg.seriesid = 1;
```

The query results in null | null | 0

Is there a way that I can avoid returning any result when the the join condition is not met?

Edit:

Realized that this query only returns one rowed result. The result set I want is to list all the genres with a column indicating whether a specific series has the genre. ( The indicator used above is 0,1 )

Comment: you want the query to **NOT** give you any result if the condition is **NOT** met ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a HAVING clause to the end of your query, e.g.

```
HAVING checked > 0
```

Note that since there's no `GROUP BY` clause on the query, the query will return at most one row. That's a valid SQL statement, but it returns an odd result, in that it's a very unusual use case that this resultset satisfies.

(Removing the COUNT() aggregate would also prevent a row from being returned, but then the statement would also then potentially return more than one row. It's not entirely clear what resultset you want returned.)

---

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q:** the result I want is list the all genres available with a column that indicates whether a specific series has the genre.

**A:** But that's an entirely different result than the one returned by the OP query.

The usual pattern for a result like that, to return "all" rows from genre (assuming there's a column or combination of columns in `genre` that is unique) using a JOIN operation would be:

```
SELECT g.id
     , g.foo
     , sg.genreid IS NULL AS checked
  FROM genre g
  LEFT
  JOIN seriesgenre sg 
    ON sg.genreid = g.id 
   AND sg.seriesid = 1
 GROUP
    BY g.id
     , g.foo
```

If `id` is unique in the `genre` table, then `g.foo` can be omitted from the `GROUP BY` clause.
That's the normal pattern.

If you want to omit rows from `genre` that don't have a matching row in seriesgenre, then just remove the `LEFT` keyword to make the join operation an "inner" join rather than an "outer" join.

If the `(genreid,seriesid)` tuple is guaranteed to be unique, we could eliminate the `GROUP BY` clause, since we'd be guaranteed that the JOIN operation would return at most one matching row from the seriesgenre table, e.g.

```
SELECT g.id
     , g.foo
     , sg.genreid IS NULL AS checked
  FROM genre g
  LEFT
  JOIN seriesgenre sg
    ON sg.genreid = g.id
   AND sg.seriesid = 1
```

---

In the more general case, if `id` is not unique in `genre`, or there's not set of columns that makes a row in `genre` unique, then we'd need to avoid collapsing rows with a `GROUP BY` clause, and use a correlated subquery instead of a JOIN operation:

```
SELECT g.id
     , g.foo
     , IFNULL( SELECT 1 
                 FROM seriesgenre sg
                WHERE sg.genreid = g.id 
                  AND sg.seriesid = 1
                 LIMIT 1
       ),0) AS checked
  FROM genre g
```

If we want to exclude rows that don't have matching row in `seriesgenre`, again using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT g.id
     , g.foo
     , ( SELECT 1 
           FROM seriesgenre sg
           WHERE sg.genreid = g.id 
             AND sg.seriesid = 1
           LIMIT 1
       ) AS checked
  FROM genre g
HAVING checked = 1
```

Comment: the result I want is to list the all genres available with a column that indicates whether a specific series has the genre.